# 9**66 != n**66 with n=9 in Node 11.6.0

Tags: node.js, precision

While looking for some black magic used in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216817/58563) to a Code Golf challenge, I've noticed the following behavior in Node 11.6.0:

```javascript
// 1) exact result with BigInts
console.log(9n ** 66n);         // 95500495(...)3841n
console.log(9n ** 66n % 79n);   // 21n

// 2) approximation with a Number literal
console.log(9 ** 66);           // 9.550049507968253e+62
console.log(9 ** 66 % 79);      // 71

// 3) approximation with a variable
let n = 9;
console.log(n ** 66);           // 9.550049507968251e+62
console.log(n ** 66 % 79);      // 69
```

Essentially, `n ** 66` with `n = 9` doesn't lead to the same result as `9 ** 66`, which is something I've never experienced before, although I've done a lot of similar weird things on Code Golf.

You can [run the above code](https://tio.run/##dc3BCoJAEMbxu08xlyCFlAoMiS7duvQO4zbYxjoru6P59ptlQYZdP/h@/xt26JXTjazYXigEZdlbQ6mx1bJxVpH3aUfOa8vxPoqyDNYxUI9KwJFvjcBdyxWOujqx@Oj7XjAkCeT58zi7wwJ2xYfdxIDNUOx1jTLURhfh3NYlOTBayKGZQqPzy4/rC3/b2z92h05jaSgyJMBwgGJK8WyAJ4EQHg) on the Try it online! service, which has Node v11.6.0 installed at the time of posting.

My current local Node version is 12.13.1, which consistently gives `71` in both cases.

Is this a known issue of Node 11.6.0? Do other Node versions and/or other JS engines behave the same way?

---

***Addendum***

Below is a simpler example with `9 ** 17`:

```javascript
console.log(9n ** 17n); // 16677181699666569n
console.log(9 ** 17);   // 16677181699666570
let n = 9;
console.log(n ** 17);   // 16677181699666568
```

Comment: Just ran this on node 14.11.0 and number literal and `n = 9` returned the same value

Comment: Odd Node.js versions are mostly development versions and act as a beta for the next even versions, which are actually supported.

BTW, I tried 9 ** 66 and let n = 9; n ** 66 in Firefox console and returned the same value, even modulo 79.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea That's right. And it would be interesting to know whether Node 10.x was doing the same thing.